# What part of speech is あたたかく?

Tags: i-adjectives, parts-of-speech

In the following sentence:

> 3 月ごろ、だんだん あたたかく なります。

Is `あたたかく` an `い`-adjective which has been turned into an adverb,

and has been used with another adverb (`だんだん`) in this sentence?

Comment: You have answered your own question. Yes. Do you fully understand the sentence now or was there something more you wanted to know?

Comment: @user3856370, Hi, I doubted that this pattern is similar to structure called adverb for adverb in other languages and I asked to be sure.

Comment: If you're deeply interested in the grammar then I think some people would argue that あたたかく is not actually an adverb even though it usually helps to think of it as one in English. Let's see what other people have to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking だんだん modifies あたたかく, it doesn’t. Both modify なります, but they have different functions.

なる is a verb of change and it requires an expression that describes what the subject will be like after the change. When you use an adjective there, you need to change it into the “adverbial” form. That’s あたたかく for あたたかい. In English, you would use an adjective as a complement of the verb, like “It will become warm.”

だんだん describes how that change happens.

Comment: Do you think of あたたかく as an adverb? We had someone in the past who seemed to get quite exercised when people suggested it was. I think he would have claimed that だんだん was but あたたかく was not.

Comment: @user3856370 - I see it as an adjective put in a particular form as the syntax demands. When you use a noun in that position, you mark it with に as in 春になる where 春に modifies なる just like あたたかく does. I wouldn’t call it an adverb. Then calling あたたかく an adverb doesn’t seem right.